# Typescript: Access static members of a class without instantiating it from an array of Constructor signatures

Tags: typescript, oop, types

I have the following code:

```
class Parent {
   public static message: string;
}

class FirstChild extends Parent {
   public static message: string = "Hello from first child";
}

class SecondChild extends Parent {
   public static message: string = "Hello from second child";
}

const children: (new() => Parent) = [FirstChild, SecondChild];
console.log(children[0].message); // tsc error: property does not exist
```

I get this error:

> property message does not exist on type new() => Parent

which makes sense, because the type is only referring to the constructor signature.

My question is: which type do I use to describe an array with constructor signatures of classes extending from a parent + the static attributes from this parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you want to reference a class object, and not an instance, you want to use:

```
typeof MyClass
```

That means that you want an array of `typeof Parent` instead:

```
const children: (typeof Parent)[] = [FirstChild, SecondChild];
console.log(children[0].message); // string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=3.9.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGtADgK4BGIAlsNBGmGhdALZJRgDmSAXFWgmSqwG5sAX2zZQkGADEyCagGEAFmRAATaEgAeaVKpjxk6LLiKl61WvSYt2Xar37QAvNABEACSQgQAe2gAzBB8GANlqaGBlNVchUXFwKGgAZSRgHxRVJRV1LR0M-URUDBwCEnJKCzpKawg2Tm4HVmc3T28-QOCqVPT1SOyYkTE0lHC+tUMuAAo0AE98JB9-OEL0AEoAbQBdZvWZOTQstQAaZO6Mw9VNoWGIHxAkADpfVkmx1UN1gAZNh5q61YE0AA9ECGnxWEA)